# how can I resize container according to content in it By using *ngIf and other directive?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have 1 container which has single image and on edit button I want to increase the size of container according to my incoming content .Here I am sharing the image of containers

Image 1:
this is container before clicking on edit button

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgAog.png

Image 2:
this is container before clicking on edit button

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xnwm.png

Answer (score 0):

you should ideally put look and feel related things into css class. you should add/remove css class on click of the button.

Comment: can you give me example ?